# Ionic 3: unable to scroll popover content in iOS

Tags: ionic3, popover

I have a page that can be displayed properly as a single page. However, when I show it using Popover controller, its content cannot be scrolled on iOS 11.2. On Android, the popover works fine.

Here is my ionic info (by running ionic info)

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:

Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Node              : v8.10.0
npm               : 5.6.0 
OS                : macOS Sierra
```

Here is my code:

```
showRoutes(event) {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(MyPage, {});
    popover.present({
      ev: event
    });
  }
```

This is MyPage html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Routes</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <div ion-item class="list-header">
      <div>Location</div>
      <div class="item-note" item-right>Distance (miles)</div>
    </div>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of evacuationPoints">
      <div>{{item.title}}</div>
      <div class="item-note" item-right>{{item.distance}}</div>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Does any one have the same problem and know how to fix? if this cannot be fixed, then Popover is useless. In the screenshot below, the list is hidden and unable to scroll up on iOS only.

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @pooja-shah: See my finding below.

Answer (score 2):

Using `<ion-scroll scrollY="true">` this instead of `<ion-content>` solves this issue.

MyPage html becomes:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Routes</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-scroll scrollY="true">
  <ion-list>
    <div ion-item class="list-header">
      <div>Location</div>
      <div class="item-note" item-right>Distance (miles)</div>
    </div>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of evacuationPoints">
      <div>{{item.title}}</div>
      <div class="item-note" item-right>{{item.distance}}</div>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-scroll>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `scrollY="false"` in the popOver component

```
<ion-content scrollY="false">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>Some item</ion-item>
    <ion-item>Some item2</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

This helped in my project, as it seemed that the inner scroll on iOS was blocking the natural popOver scroll

Comment: Issue still present on Ionic 6.
Seems counterintuitive but that fixed the issue for me on iOS and kept working just fine on Android. Dunno why it had a -1 vote.